# How to perform one (part of a) function when any key is pressed and another when spacebar is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've tried many different things but I'm stuck. I'm building a website where the user can write something (using an input), it'll appear below as they type and fade using a CSS animation upon pressing spacebar. Pressing enter will call reset and the input will be cleared.

As you can see below I've used onkeyup to call a function that'll write whatever you type in the H1 part. Except right now, whenever you type anything it starts fading immediately. I want the word to start fading once you press spacebar. How do I do this?

I've tried this:

```
document.getElementById("Hello")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        document.getElementById("new").style.opacity = "0";
    }
});
```

and I thought it would work but it didn't. I also tried putting the if (event.keyCode == 32) part inside my first function but it didn't work either.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="Hello" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"/>
<input type="reset" id="Reset">
</form>

<h1 id="new"></h1>
```

Javascript:

```
    window.myFunction = function(input) {
   document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = input;
   document.getElementById("new").style.opacity = "0";
```

CSS:

```
#Reset {display: none;}
  h1 {font: bold 200% Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
    color: white;
    transition: opacity 6s linear;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 16.5em;
    margin: 2em 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;}
```

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Use the handler you add with `addEventListener` and get rid of the "onkeyup" attribute in the HTML.